# inheritance in C# "must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial"

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor

I was trying to use `class Account` as parent and `class Login` as child object.

Here is `Account` code looks like

```
 class Account
        {
            private string account;
            private string password;
            private string Email;

            public Account();
            public Account(string _account, string _password, string _Email)
            {
                this.setAcount(_account).setPassword(_password).setEmail(_Email);
            }

.......
}
```

And here is `Class Login`

```
class Login : Account
    {
        private bool login_status ;
        private static int try_count ;

        public Login()
        {
            login_status = false;
            try_count = 0;
        }
......
}
```

However it pop up error messages

> error1    'team2.Account.Account()' must declare a body because it is not
>   marked abstract, extern, or partial

Comment: The error is pretty straight forward. Your constructor has no body. If you really want a constructor that does nothing, you can just throw in some empty braces: `public Account() { }`

Comment: Yes you got it. Thanks, it hard for me in unfamiliar language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not valid declaration:

```
public Account();
```

Constructor has to have body:

```
public Account() { };
```

Comment: ahahahahah, how silly I am. Thanks, you have been a great help.